# Hide buttons on HTML Web resource landing page, Dynamics 365

Tags: button, dynamics-crm, hide, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a Site Map link that opens up a Web Resource .html page. Everything works great except the 3 menu items highlighted which are there by default, but there is no need for them.

[image]

Could someone help me to remove them? Note that Ribbon Work Bench didn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [Attila answer on community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/168954) for this only unsupported solution.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
window.top.document.getElementById("crmTopBar").style.display = "";
window.top.document.getElementById("crmContentPanel").style.top = "112px";
};

window.top.document.getElementById("crmTopBar").style.display = "none";
window.top.document.getElementById("crmContentPanel").style.top = "50px";
```